# How to get correct instance that inherits from abstract class during runtime in java?

Tags: java, oop

I have a `Player` class where I need to downcast the abstract class type to one of its implemented types. The abstract class is called `World` which is extended by `Map1`, `Map2` etc... classes. I want to make level system where the `Map1` transitions to `Map2` and `Map2` to `Map3` etc...

What I tried is the following in `Player.java`:

```
public World getCurrentWorldType() {
        World currWorld = getWorld(); 
        if (currWorld instanceof Map1) {
            return (Map1) currWorld;
        } else if (currWorld instanceof Map2) {
            return (Map2) currWorld; 
        }
        return currWorld;
}
```

And I want to use it as follows also in `Player.java`:

```
String mapName = getCurrentWorldType().getName();
```

This however results in RuntimeException if it were `Map2`. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: This feels like fighting against the river instead of going with the flow: if you have code that deals with `World` instances, it should not matter what subclass the objects "really" are, any function that this codepath needs to call should be exposed through `World`, and should work because all subclasses (no matter how deeply) either inherit or override them. If you need transition logical, create a `void transitionTo(World next) { ... }` and make that work cleanly?

Comment: not sure if i got you but try this
World w = getWorld();
if(w.getClass().equals(Map1.class)){
((Map1.class)w).getName
}else{
\\ not sure which method you will call here
}

Comment: the cause of exception cause there is no getname method in map2 class so what you want to call instead or do not call any thing if you like

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans true but the subclasses are specialized so some could have methods that other subclasses don't have right? I also edited the thread with a better solution but it still causes a problem which I mentioned.

Comment: "I also edited the thread with a better solution" This "better solution" does a lot of work for the same result. In the end, it still returns a `World`.

Comment: Remember not to edit your post to be "a question, and then another, different question". SO posts are not just for you, they're also for every future visitor to the site, and [a good question](/help/how-to-ask) tries to get one and only one thing answered. Work edits into the post as a whole instead, to keep it a coherent question that's asking about one thing. In this case: just add `getName` to your superclass as public or protected method so that your subclasses inherit it if they don't explicitly define it themselves?

Comment: With that said, I suggest you read more about the concept of "code to the interface not the implementation". `World` subclasses should be used only through the functions that are defined in the `World` superclass.

Comment: Why do you think you need the concrete type here? How are you using your `World` objects where you think this is necessary?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you mean that all subclasses of abstract class should not implement more than what is declared as `abstract` in the superclass? And thus they should only implement what needs to be implemented.

Comment: @LinkCoder I think that's a good rule of thumb, yes, but might be too strict. More importantly, if you declare a `World` variable anywhere, it should be treated as such and shouldn't need to know what subclass actually implements the behavior. I cannot explain it as well as other's already have. Like I said, read more about "code to the interface" and look at examples in the standard Java library, such as the Collections framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling methods defined on the abstract class, no need to cast to the concrete subclass. The entire point of polymorphism is not needing to cast to the subclass.

```
abstract class World {
    String getName() {
        return "no name" ;
    }
}
```

If the subclass overrides the superclass implementation, that overridden method is executed. If the subclass does not, the superclass method is executed. The JVM handles that for you automatically.

```
class Earth extends World {
    @Override
    String getName() {
        return "Earth" ;
    }
}
```

And another subclass.

```
class Mars extends World {
    @Override
    String getName() {
        return "Mars" ;
    }
}
```

When you call `getName` on any kind of `World`, the JVM locates and executes the appropriate method. No casting involved.

```
List< World > worlds =
    List.of(
        new Earth() ,
        new Mars() 
    );
for( World world : worlds ) {
    System.out.println ( world.getName() ) ;  // No need to cast. 
}
```

When run.

> Earth
>
> Mars

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my implementation is that it does not really adhere to OOP rules. As @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans and @ Code-Apprentice were appointing to in the comments: "if you have code that deals with `World` instances, it should not matter what subclass the objects "really" are, any function that this codepath needs to call should be exposed through World, and should work because all subclasses (no matter how deeply) either inherit or override them" and "`World` subclasses should be used only through the functions that are defined in the `World` superclass".

So one of the solutions is given by @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans: "Add getName to your superclass as public or protected method so that your subclasses inherit it if they don't explicitly define it themselves?"

OR as what has been mentioned by the accepted answer.

Both give the right notion of how it should be implemented.